# スクロールバーが二重に表示されるページ(Bluesky, bsky.app)で`window.scrollTo()`が働かない

Tags: javascript

他に同様のサイトがあるかはわかりませんが、[Bluesky](https://bsky.app/)ではブラウザのスクロールバーと別にページ内部にもスクロールバーが表示されます。そして`window.scrollTo()`ではブラウザのスクロールバーを動かすことはできても、内部のスクロールバーは動かせないので実質的に働きません。

`body`タグに`overflow-y: auto`が指定されてる事が原因かとも思いましたが、以下のようにしてもダメでした。

```js
window.onload = function () {
        document.body.style.overflowY = "visible";
}
```

また、以下のコードを試したところ、`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'overflowY')`とエラーが出ます。

```js
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(const div in divs){
    div.style.overflowY = "visible";
}
```

スクロールバーが二重に表示される原因は別にあるかもしれませんが、いずれにせよ内部のスクロールバーを動かす方法は無いでしょうか？

なお、javascriptを動かしてるのは[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)内のユーザースクリプトです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(私の環境では bsky.app にはスクロールバーは現れないので動作確認はできませんが)
一般的には、スクロール可能な要素(`overflow`の値が `auto` や `scroll`になっている)の `scrollTo()` などを呼べばよいです。`window.scrollTo()` ではなく。

もし `<body>` が対象要素であるなら、`document.body.scrollTo(...)` です。

Comment: `overflow-y: auto`が設定されてる'.r-1rnoaur'という`class`のdivに対して`scrollTo()`を実行しましたが、何も起きません。エラーメッセージなどは表示されず、`scrollTo()`自体は実行されてることを`console.log()`で確認しました。実際の環境を見ないと原因がわからないかもしれませんが、コードを譲渡するので少しだけでも見て頂くことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 問題を再現できる最小のHTML+CSSを作って、質問文に含めてください。

Comment: クラスに'.r-1rnoaur'を含むものが二つあり、誤って親の方を取得していました。また、`scrollTo()`は以下のページではパラメータ名が`top`, `left`などになってますが、Chromeの開発者ツールでは`x`,`y`,`animated`(true or false)と警告が出たのでそれを修正したところ動作しました。ありがとうございます。 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: `window`に対して`scrollTo()`を使う場合、上記ページ通りのパラメータになるようです。